# Sum by groups in two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have the following DF:

```
DAY           BRAND     SOLD
2018/04/10     KIA       10
2018/04/15     KIA        5
2018/05/01     KIA        7
2018/05/06     KIA        3
2018/04/04     BMW        2
2018/05/25     BMW        8
2018/06/19     BMW        5
2018/06/14     BMW        1
```

I would like to sum the units sold by month and repeat them in every row where the date belongs to the month (the sum can't be done for different BRANDS in the same MONTH, that's a condition), like this:

```
DAY           BRAND     SOLD   TOTAL
2018/04/10     KIA       10      15
2018/04/15     KIA        5      15
2018/05/01     KIA        7      10
2018/05/06     KIA        3      10
2018/04/04     BMW        2       2
2018/05/25     BMW        8       8
2018/06/19     BMW        5       6
2018/06/14     BMW        1       6
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` after extracting the 'month' from the 'DAY' column and use that as grouping variable along with "BRAND"

```
df1$TOTAL <- with(df1, ave(SOLD, BRAND, 
        format(as.Date(DAY, "%Y/%m/%d"), "%m"), FUN = sum))
df1$TOTAL
#[1] 15 15 10 10  2  8  6  6
```

---

Or in `dplyr/lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   group_by(BRAND, MONTH = month(ymd(DAY))) %>%
   mutate(TOTAL = sum(SOLD))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   BRAND, MONTH [5]
#  DAY        BRAND  SOLD MONTH TOTAL
#  <chr>      <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
#1 2018/04/10 KIA      10     4    15
#2 2018/04/15 KIA       5     4    15
#3 2018/05/01 KIA       7     5    10
#4 2018/05/06 KIA       3     5    10
#5 2018/04/04 BMW       2     4     2
#6 2018/05/25 BMW       8     5     8
#7 2018/06/19 BMW       5     6     6
#8 2018/06/14 BMW       1     6     6
```

Remove the 'MONTH' column after `ungroup`ing with `select(-MONTH)` if needed

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DAY = c("2018/04/10", "2018/04/15", "2018/05/01", 
"2018/05/06", "2018/04/04", "2018/05/25", "2018/06/19", "2018/06/14"
), BRAND = c("KIA", "KIA", "KIA", "KIA", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", 
"BMW"), SOLD = c(10L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```